# putting a JPanel in a JFrame: setContentPane() and add() both work?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

putting a `JPanel` in a `JFrame`: `setContentPane()` and `add()` both seem to work.  Is there any technical difference?

One example from web has the following. Changing `frame.setContentPane(panel)` to `frame.add(panel)` seems to produce the same behavior.

```
//file: Calculator.java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
  JTextField theDisplay = new JTextField();

  public Calculator() {
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;  gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    ContainerListener listener = new ContainerAdapter() {
      public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
        Component comp = e.getChild();
        if (comp instanceof JButton)
          ((JButton)comp).addActionListener(Calculator.this);
      }
    };
    addContainerListener(listener);
    gbc.gridwidth = 4;
    addGB(this, theDisplay, 0, 0);
    // make the top row
    JPanel topRow = new JPanel();
    topRow.addContainerListener(listener);
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    addGB(topRow, new JButton("C"), 0, 0);
    gbc.weightx = 0.33;
    addGB(topRow, new JButton("%"), 1, 0);
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    addGB(topRow, new JButton("+"), 2, 0 );
    gbc.gridwidth = 4;
    addGB(this, topRow, 0, 1);
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;  gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    // make the digits
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            addGB(this, new JButton("" + ((2-j)*3+i+1) ), i, j+2);
    // -, x, and divide
    addGB(this, new JButton("-"), 3, 2);
    addGB(this, new JButton("x"), 3, 3);
    addGB(this, new JButton("\u00F7"), 3, 4);
    // make the bottom row
    JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel();
    bottomRow.addContainerListener(listener);
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    addGB(bottomRow, new JButton("0"), 0, 0);
    gbc.weightx = 0.33;
    addGB(bottomRow, new JButton("."), 1, 0);
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    addGB(bottomRow, new JButton("="), 2, 0);
    gbc.gridwidth = 4;
    addGB(this, bottomRow, 0, 5);
  }

  void addGB(Container cont, Component comp, int x, int y) {
    if ((cont.getLayout() instanceof GridBagLayout) == false)
      cont.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc.gridx = x; gbc.gridy = y;
    cont.add(comp, gbc);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("C"))
      theDisplay.setText("");
    else
      theDisplay.setText(theDisplay.getText()
                         + e.getActionCommand());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setSize(200, 250);
    frame.setLocation(200, 200);
    frame.setContentPane(new Calculator());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Another has the following.  Changing `frame.add(panel)` to `frame.setContentPane(panel)` seems to produce the same behavior.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class recMod {
  public enum RecFieldNames {
    FIRST_NAME("First Name:"),
    LAST_NAME("Last Name:"),
    VENDOR("Vendor:"),
    VENDOR_LOC_CODE("Vendor Location Code:"),
    USER_EMAIL("User Email Address:"),
    USER_NAME("Username:"),
    PASSWORD("Password:"),
    USER_CODE("User Code:");

    private String name;
    private RecFieldNames(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
  }

  private static final int FIELD_COLS = 7;
  private Map<RecFieldNames, JTextField> recFieldMap =
    new HashMap<RecFieldNames, JTextField>();
  //JButton[] recButtons = new JButton[3];

  public recMod() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Record Modify");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.FIRST_NAME, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.LAST_NAME, 2, 0, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.EAST);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.VENDOR, 0, 1, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.VENDOR_LOC_CODE, 2, 1, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.USER_EMAIL, 0, 2, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.USER_NAME, 0, 3, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.PASSWORD, 2, 3, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    addLabelField(panel, RecFieldNames.USER_CODE, 0, 4, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    //frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public String getFieldText(RecFieldNames rfn) {
    return recFieldMap.get(rfn).getText();
  }

  private void addLabelField(JPanel p, RecFieldNames recFieldNames, int x,
      int y, int width, int height, int labelAlign, int fieldAlign) {

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(recFieldNames.getName());
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(FIELD_COLS);
    recFieldMap.put(recFieldNames, textField);

    gbc.gridx = x;
    gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridwidth = width;
    gbc.gridheight = height;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.weighty = 0.0;
    int midInset = (x == 2) ? 40 : 5;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, midInset, 5, 5);
    gbc.anchor = labelAlign;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    p.add(label, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = x + 1;
    gbc.anchor = fieldAlign;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    p.add(textField, gbc);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    new recMod();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The content pane of the frame is a JPanel.

So if you use frame.add( another panel ), then you have a structure like:

```
- JFrame
    - content pane
        - another panel
```

If you use frame setContentPane( another panel ) you have:

```
- JFrame
    - another panel
```

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Adding Components to the Content Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane).